# Key Stroke of SHIFT i displays "BIG PAPA" instead (full Virus/Anti Spyware Scans complete!)

Tags: macros, microsoft-office

This is a bit weird, and seems to be localized on three machines with MS Office 2007 and 2010, have scanned all three units (one of them was removed from the network, completely formatted, and the OS reinstalled) problem is STILL occuring, have checked all macros, (none installed or running) seems to occur in Word, Outlook, and Excel, Pressing the SHIFT key and the i to capitalize into "I" yeilds "BIG PAPA" instead, (all caps) have checked for any keystroke tracking software, as well as the sticky keys settings...any ideas would be appreciated. (of course a google search yeilded no results)

Comment: custom keyboard mapping, perhaps?

Comment: Does it do it if you start Office in Safe Mode (Ctrl-Click to open in safe mode, or run the Office application with the `/safe` switch)?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like an auto-correction issue. Under File, select Options. Then select Proofing on the left side. Finally select the AutoCorrect button on the right side. This should bring up a new window. Near the bottom, see if anyone has added an option to auto-change I to BIG PAPA. This was my favorite prank in college.

Comment: OP's case was rather benign. Before I outgrew that prank (I was about 11) I was more "creative." :)